# SSRS query using WITH XMLNAMESPACES not returning dataset

Tags: xml, t-sql, ssrs-2008, xml-namespaces, reportingservices-2005

The sql query I have written for a SSRS report executes perfectly in SSMS but fails to return a result when run in a SSRS report. There is no error on the report server or on the database server. The SSRS report renders but contains no data.
I tried running SQL profiler and the query does not show up at all. I have several other reports on the server that run correctly and the query appears in SQL profiler.
The only thing that is different in the broken report is that I am querying XML data using `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:hl7-org:v3')`

I get the same result running against SQL Server 2005 and 2008

Here is the query, any ideas on why nothing is returned when run in SSRS. I have modified the query to remove/modified client info which may cause a syntax error, but the unmodified query runs and returns results when run in SSMS

```
Declare @MinDate datetime;
Declare @MaxDate datetime;
DECLARE @fooData TABLE (msgId varchar(100), TransactionName     varchar(30),SourceSystem varchar(12),MsgDay date) 

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:hl7-org:v3')

INSERT INTO @fooData
SELECT 
       MsgLogID as msgId
      ,TransactionName =
            CASE LEFT(MsgBody,28)
                    --WHEN '<qqqResult' THEN 'qqqResult'
                    WHEN '<qqqResult xmlns=' THEN 'qqqResult'
                    ELSE 'qqqqRevised'
                    END
    , SourceSystem =
            CASE LEFT(MsgBody,21)
                    --WHEN '<qqqResult' THEN CONVERT(XML,[MsgBody]).value('(/qqqResult/receiver/device/id/@extension)[1]','varchar(1000)')
                    WHEN '<qqqResult' THEN CONVERT(XML,[MsgBody]).value('(/qqqResult/sender/device/id/@extension)[1]','varchar(1000)')
                    ELSE CONVERT(XML,[MsgBody]).value('(/qqqRevised/sender/device/id/@extension)[1]','varchar(1000)')
                    END
     , Convert(date,[MsgDateTime]) as MsgDay

  FROM [foo].[dbo].[fooMegerPerson_WCF]


  WHERE [TransactionStatus] = 'Valid'

SELECT @MaxDate=DATEADD(DAY,0,datediff(day,0, MAX([MsgDateTime]))) ,@MinDate=DATEADD(DAY,0,datediff(day,0, MIN ([MsgDateTime])) )FROM [foo].[dbo].[fooMegerPerson_WCF]

-- Declare a temp table for the query msg type so that we can create a join
DECLARE @msgNameTable TABLE (msgName varchar(30))
INSERT INTO @msgNameTable (msgName)
Values ('qqqResult'),('fooRevised')

DECLARE @sourceTable TABLE (sourceName varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (sourceName)
Values ('foo_1'),('foo_2') 
--Select * from @msgNameTable
-- create a date table containing every day between start and end
DECLARE @datetable TABLE (d date) 
INSERT INTO @datetable
SELECT     TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1) Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, 
@MinDate)
FROM         sys.all_objects a CROSS JOIN
                      sys.all_objects b

-- cross join to create a daily entry for every msg type and every source system                      
DECLARE @dateNameSourceTable  TABLE (d date, msgName varchar (30),sourceName varchar(10)) 
INSERT INTO @dateNameSourceTable                     
                    Select dt.d, mn.msgName, st.sourceName from @datetable dt CROSS JOIN @msgNameTable mn CROSS JOIN @sourceTable st
--SELECT * FROM @dateNameSourceTable



Select Count(x.msgId) AS MessageCount,dsn.msgName AS TransactionName ,dsn.d, dsn.sourceName 
FROM @fooData   as X
  RIGHT JOIN @dateNameSourceTable dsn ON x.MsgDay = dsn.d  AND x.SourceSystem = dsn.sourceName  AND x.TransactionName = dsn.msgName
   Group By dsn.d, dsn.msgName, dsn.sourceName
  Order By dsn.d, dsn.sourceName , dsn.msgName
```

Comment: Hi, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing that is different in the broken report is that I am
>   querying XML data using ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:hl7-org:v3')

Well, this is a quite important *only thing*...

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
'<root><a>test</a></root>';

SELECT @XML.value('(/root/a)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

returns "test" as expected

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'tmpUri')
SELECT @XML.value('(/root/a)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

returns "NULL"

While

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
'<root xmlns="tmpUri"><a>test</a></root>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'tmpUri')
SELECT @XML.value('(/root/a)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

returns "test" but the same without the namespace hint would return "NULL"...

There is one general trick to omit all namespaces: Use a wildcard!

```
SELECT @XML.value('(/*:root/*:a)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the namespace tip. I ended up rebuilding the report from scratch using the namespace wildcard and it works